# I want to create a regex for some numbers and character with multiple occurrence and 0 or more occurrence of [number-number]. Below is my regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex should pass for -

1. 90[3-8]$$$$$$$
2. 90
3. 90[3-8]
4. $$$*%$90[1-2]%
5. 90[3-8][3-8]
6. [3-8]90[3-8]

Regex should fail for (should have 0 or 1 occurrence for -)

1. ---
2. 90[3-8]$$$$$$$-
3. -90-

My Regex which is not working :

`^[A-Za-z0-9?*$%[\]]*$|^[\[[0-9]*-[0-9]*\]*$`

Answer (score 1):

Created a rexeg and all test are passing with the same

```
^(([A-Za-z0-9?*$%])*([\[[a-z0-9]*-[a-z0-9]*\])*)*$
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that you use, might lead to catastrophic backtracking as there are a lot of optional parts, which are also inside a repeated group. See [this example](https://regex101.com/r/qjjuPg/1).

If you want to match `[number-number]` you can use `\[\d+-\d+]`

What you might do, is repeat either a single character in the group, and it will also prevent matching an empty string:

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9?*$%]|\[\d+-\d+])+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[A-Za-z0-9?*$%]` Match any of the listed
  - `|` Or
  - `\[\d+-\d+]` Match a pattern `[number-number]`
- `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UaO1yI/1)

```js
const regex = /^(?:[A-Za-z0-9?*$%]|\[\d+-\d+])+$/;
["90[3-8]$$$$$$$",
  "90",
  "90[3-8]",
  "$$$*%$90[1-2]%",
  "90[3-8][3-8]",
  "[3-8]90[3-8]",
  "$$$*%$90[1-2]%$$$*%$90[1-2]%$$$*%$90[1-2%",
  "-----",
  "90[3-8]$$$$$$$-",
  "-90-"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(regex.test(s) ? `Match --> ${s}` : `No match --> ${s}`)
);
```